# Do Typescript generics use type erasure to implement generics?

Tags: generics, typescript

Meaning you cannot use something like this?

```
class Helpers
{
    static ObjectAs<T>(val: any): T {
        if (!(val instanceof T)) {
            return null;
        }

        return <T>val;
    }
}
```

Any workaround to get the underlying type of the generic declaration?

**Update 1:**

As Ryan Cavanaugh mentioned, when compiled, the whole type system is erased, more like Java's implementation of Generics. I believe .Net implementation of Generics to preserve type information in the compiled code is better than Java.
However, I cannot help but wonder, why is not possible to permit full runtime introspection of generic types and generic type parameters in TypeScript? Why designers of TypeScript decided to remove all generic type information at runtime?

The following TypeScript code:

```
function As<T>(n: any): T {
    if (n instanceof T) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

var obj: Object = 1;
var x = As<number>(obj);
```

Could be translated to this JavaScript code:

```
function As(n, T) {
    if (n instanceof T) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

var obj = 1;
var x = As(obj, Number);
```

Preserving the type information at runtime and compatibility with the js code!

**Update 2:**
I've posted the issue on CodePlex, hoping to get more from TypeScript people
https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/550262

Comment: What an awesome question... hoping it doesnt closed SO style

Comment: Page 2 of the specification states that all type information is erased before the JavaScript is emitted by the compiler. Given that information my best guess would say that your instanceof operator would be meaningless in the runtime environment. My best advice would be to create a post in their forum discussing the specification: http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/topics/5488/language-specification. You might get them thinking about supporting this if it isn't already.

Comment: @ErikNedwidek Already on it :)

Comment: You could not do what you suggest, because you can call functions dynamically at runtime, so the transpiler would not necessarily know to convert a call to `As(n)` into `As(n, T)`. Not to mention it would institute a breaking change with a whole lot of existing TypeScript code. Also, what happens when T is number or string or boolean? You cannot call `instanceof` on it, nor can you pass it in as a parameter. You'd have to implement some TS requirement that if `instanceof` is called inside a function, your generics must be classes and cannot be primitives.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The type system is wholly erased. You can see this in the generated code for any generic function.

That said, for classes, there's still some runtime information left. You could write this:

```
class A { }
class B { }
function As<T>(n: any, type: { new(...args: any[]): T }): T {
    if(n instanceof type) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return null as any;
    }
}

var x = new A();
var y = new B();
console.log(As(x, A));
console.log(As(x, B));
```

Comment: Having type argument to preserve types at runtime makes perfect sense, however I wonder why TypeScript designers decided to removes generic types altogether in the generated js code? see the update in the original post

Comment: @KamyarNazeri "Having type argument to preserve types at runtime makes perfect sense". But isn't Javascript a duck-typed language? Since the target environment doesn't have a concept of type, then it makes perfect sense for complete type erasure.

Comment: @Aron I believe you misread what I meant. the *type argument* is preserved in the compiled js file considering the method signature is preserved! However it is Generic type declaration - when not present in the method signature - that is removed by type erasure. Besides it is true that JavaScript is a duck-typed language, however TypeScript being a superset to JavaScript I believe Generic type erasure could be a little more problem

Comment: The update presumes that all types in the type system are manifested by a corresponding constructor function, which is definitely not the case -- anonymous types, interfaces, etc all don't have obvious runtime objects that correspond to them

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh I've posted the issue on codeplex, could you be more specific there: https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/550262

Comment: Javascript is not duck-typed. Duck typing assumes a type is suitable if it has the correct properties and functions, and javascript is not doing this kind of checking.  Typescript actually does duck typing, and will consider two types equal if if they share the same shape, even if defined under different names. JavaScript is dynamically typed.

Comment: Thank you, I just needed a true C# `as` operator replacement as well. I fixed the error `Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'T' (2322)` error.