# Generic React components in TypeScript/JSX?

Tags: generics, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I would like to create pluggable React components. Components are resolved by their class names, so I am naturally drawn to generics; but this doesn't seem to work.

```
class Div<P, S, C extends React.Component> extends React.Component<void, void> {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <C /> // error: Cannot find name 'C'.
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Is there an alternative way to write pluggable TypeScript components?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The accepted answer for this question still stands, due to TypeScript types being erased, however as of Typescript 2.9, [generic JSX components are supported](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#generic-type-arguments-in-jsx-elements)

The example provided is:

```
class GenericComponent<P> extends React.Component<P> {
    internalProp: P;
}
type Props = { a: number; b: string; };

const x = <GenericComponent<Props> a={10} b="hi"/>; // OK
const y = <GenericComponent<Props> a={10} b={20} />; // Error
```

Just thought it worth mentioning for anyone who ends up here via the question title.

Comment: What a weird example (I of course followed the link and saw that it's an official one). I really hope people don't start writing such things thinking that that's how it must be done.

Answer (score 12):

This isn't possible to do using generics, though it's not clear why you would want to use generics for this problem rather than just providing the inner element using the normal `props` mechanism.

The reason is that types are erased, so you need to provide the class constructor to the class so that it has a reference to the value to instantiate in `C`. But there's no place other than the JSX `props` (or `state` or whatever you need to do) for you to pass in that value.

In other words, instead of writing

```
// not sure what you would expect the syntax to be?
const elem = <Div<Foo> ... />;
```

You should write

```
const elem = <Div myChild={Foo} />
```

and consume it in your `render` as

```
const Child = this.props.myChild;
return <div><Child /></div>;
```

As an aside, the correct constraint is `new() => React.Component` rather than `React.Component` -- remember that the things you write in the JSX (`<Div>`, etc) are the *constructors* for classes, not the class *instances*.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what it means for a type to be erased? Are you talking about how the types disappear when the typescript code is compiled to javascript? (e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24469856/4975230)?)