# How to inherit component in react native with typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, native

I wrote a `BaseListPage` component like this:

```
export default class BaseListPage extends Component<Props, State> {
```

and, I want to write another component inherited `BaseListPage`, like this:

```
export default class DynamicListPage extends BaseListPage<Props, State> {
```

but it prompts `Type 'BaseListPage' is not generic.`.

I'm a new typescripter in react-native, please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic React components in TypeScript/JSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406448/generic-react-components-in-typescript-jsx)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're passing type arguments to your `BaseListPage` class with the `BaseListPage<Props, State>` part of `class DynamicListPage extends BaseListPage<Props, State>`, but the class doesn't accept any type arguments.

You can let `BaseListPage` take type arguments by making it a 'generic':

```
class BaseListPage<Props, State> extends Component<Props, State> {
```

see - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

---

Since a react component could have any shape of props or state, those type arguments allow you to define exactly what they will look like for a given instance of a class, allowing you to run the necessary type checks.

Eg.

```
 interface Props {
   foo: string
 }

 class MyComponent extends Component<Props> {
   render() {
     console.log(this.props.foo) // Fine
     console.log(this.props.bar) // Error

     ...
   }
 }
```

So either, define the exact Props and State that a `BaseListPage` component can have like so, thereby removing the need for it to be generic:

```
 interface BaseListPageProps {
   foo: string
 }

 interface BaseListPageState {
   bar: string
 }

 class BaseListPage extends Component<BaseListPageProps, BaseListPageState> {
   ...
 }

 class DynamicListPage extends BaseListPage {
  render() {
     console.log(this.props.foo) // Fine
     console.log(this.state.bar) // Fine

     console.log(this.props.bar) // Error

     ...
   }
 }
```

or let it be generic, allowing the DynamicListPage to decide the Props and State types:

```
 class BaseListPage<Props, State> extends Component<Props, State> {
   ...
 }

 interface DynamicListPageProps {
   foo: string
 }

 interface DynamicListPageState {
   bar: string
 }

 class DynamicListPage extends BaseListPage<DynamicListPageProps, DynamicListPageState> {
```

Better yet, compose via composition, not inheritance. https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
export default class DynamicListPage extends BaseListPage {
```

instead of

```
export default class DynamicListPage extends BaseListPage<Props, State> {
```

That should be enough to make your code work as you expected.

More info about this topic can be found here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html