# How to refer to the value of a type parameter in a generic method

Tags: generics, typescript

This code won't compile because the first parameter of the call to CreateItem is not a variable in scope.

```
  abstract class Catalog<ItemType, IRaw> {
    private CreateItem<ItemType, IRaw>(c: new (raw: IRaw) => ItemType, raw: IRaw): ItemType {
      return new c(raw);
    }
    public ServiceUrl: string;
    public Items: KnockoutObservableArray<ItemType> = ko.observableArray<ItemType>();
    public LoadState: KnockoutObservable<LoadState> = ko.observable<LoadState>(LoadState.NotStarted);
    private loadChunk(): void {
      var that = this;
      if (that.LoadState() === LoadState.NotStarted)
        that.LoadState(LoadState.Loading);
      if (that.LoadState() === LoadState.Loading) {
        $.get(this.ServiceUrl, that.getChunkParameters()).then((result: Array<IRaw>) => {
          if (result.length === 0) {
            that.LoadState(LoadState.Complete)
          } else {
            for (var raw of result){
              let foo = this.CreateItem(ItemType, raw);
              that.Items.push(foo);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

How do I get a variable reference to the value of the generic parameter ItemType so I can pass it to CreateInstance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Only classes can be used as values. Other types, generic parameters in particular, are not values, they are not preserved when typescript is compiled to javascript. That variable must be provided explicitly to `loadChunk()` somehow, either as value argument similar to `CreateItem()`, or accessible as a property of `Catalog` class, which in turn must be initialized somehow.

See also [Do Typescript generics use type erasure to implement generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469856/do-typescript-generics-use-type-erasure-to-implement-generics).

Comment: I was afraid this might be the case. I'm rewriting to exploit inheritance but it's not as flexible as composition might have been. Oh well, back to the drawing board.