# How to initialize a variable in a class to its generic value using Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I am building a component to hold information about fields for use in a form.  I need to hold various data objects to create generic routines for working with the data.

```
export class DataField<T> {
    /**
     * Data field name IE: database column name, JSON field, etc.
     */
    private Name_: string;
    private Size_: number;
    /**
     * The data type for this field. IE: String, Boolean, etc. Note that this is set internally, and is not set by a passed reference
     */
    private Type_: T;
    // private Type_: { new(): T ;}   <- this has not worked either

    /**
     * Class constructor
     * @param FieldName string Name of the Field
     * @param FieldSize number Field Size
     */
    constructor(FieldName:string, FieldSize:number) {
        this.Name_ = FieldName;
        this.Size_ = FieldSize;
    }

    /**
     * Get the data type for the value
     * @returns string The TypeOf the value
     */
    get Type(): string {
        return (typeof this.Type_).toString();
    }
}
```

The problem that I have is that the field Type_ is not initialized to anything, so it is always set as undefined.  When I create the DataField with the generic, it might look like:

```
new DataField<string>('FullName', 32);
```

The generic type T is now `string`, but I want to be able to get the Type_ variable set so the call to `get Type()` will return a string.

Comment: `get Type()` *does* return a string as it is... doesn't it?

Comment: `Type_` is never assigned a value... so how can it be anything but `undefined`? What do you expect to be the content of `Type_`?

Comment: If you are asking about how to get a default value, when you have only `T` as generic type parameter - the answer is you can't, type parameters are erased from generated javascript. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42823198/how-to-refer-to-the-value-of-a-type-parameter-in-a-generic-method/42823352#42823352 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469856/do-typescript-generics-use-type-erasure-to-implement-generics

Comment: @Sébastien I return a string value, such as 'boolean', 'number', 'string', etc. from Type_.  I want this to tell me the type of data.  You are correct in that it is not initialized to anything, which is what I am trying to do, so that I can get the type from it.

Comment: "I want this to tell me the type of data" the type of data of **which** data? If you never give a value to the `Type_` property, then it has no other type than `undefined`. I guess I still don't understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: With a generic, I can create the DataField<boolean> which uses T internally to mean boolean on all line definitions (private Type_: T is really then private Type_:boolean).  As this is a library class, the type can be different for each field. So when I am preparing to work with the data, I want to be able to check the Type_ (boolean is what I would expect in this comment example) so that my code can prepare to accept a boolean and work with it, differently from another internal type (number, string) or even a custom type (which is a class TEST_DATA for instance).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to pass the type as a parameter to your constructor; in TypeScript there's no need explicitly set it as a generic:

```
class DataField<T> {

    constructor( 
        private type: {new (...args): T}, 
        private fieldName: string, 
        private fieldSize: number) {}

    public getType(): string {
        return this.type.name;
    }
}

const field = new DataField(String, 'name', 256);
console.log(field.getType()); // outputs "String"
```

Remember classes in JS are no more than functions, the `class` declaration is syntactic sugar. "Types" in JavaScript are no more than the constructor (as in the function object itself) that when called with `new` will created an object with the desired prototype.

Note you really don't need a generic as your current class is built (I just left it for sake of example); it would function just fine without it. You could replace `{new (...args): T}` with `{new (...args): any}`. You would need a generic if you wanted a data *container* class that returned actual values with the correct type:

```
class DataContainer<T> {
   // other class stuff

   public getValue(): T {
      // do stuff to return value
   }
}
```

Comment: I guess there is no way to do it with the Generic, and not have to pass the type again to the constructor on the new DataField(_TYPE_, 'name', 256) where _TYPE_ is boolean, number, etc.?

Comment: I guess the issue is that if I pass the type as you suggest String (which Visual Studio Code warns is a type being used as a value) then I could just as easily pass the text representation 'string' and simply the constructor even further.  I was really hoping to be able to do the same thing, but use the generic type, without the extra constructor variable.  I guess this cannot be done at the current time with Typescript.  I know that Javascript will not support this, but it was mostly for the type checking in Typescript and then library handling afterwards.

Comment: If TypeScript did support that it would just be syntactic sugar for a ctor variable. Note there is a big difference between `string` and `String`: `string` is a primitive JavaScript value type (of `number`, `boolean`, `object`, and `undefined`, among others), and `String` is a native function (aka class). As an symbol, `string` only exists in TypeScript. Note you should **not** use native classes (`String`, `Number`, etc.) to create new primitive values: `35 !== new Number('35')`

Comment: I am not using the String, but string, but yes, the syntactic sugar would be nice.