# How to get the type of T inside generic method in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

I have a generic method in a class.,

```
export class BaseService {
    public getAll<T>(): Observable<T> {
        // get type of T

        // const type = typeof(T); // Tried this but getting compilation exceptions 

        return this.http.get<T>(this.actionUrl + 'getAll');
    }
}
```

I'll be calling the method like below, from few other typescript classes.

```
this.service.getAll<SubscriberData>().subscribe(response => {
      // Response
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    }, () => {
      // do something commonly
    });
```

When i tried this getting the following exception

```
const type = typeof(T);
```

> 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

**Edit:**

I'm trying to get the type of a class which is calling the generic method. For Ex: `getAll<SubscriberData>` i want to get the type `SubscriberData` inside that method.

How can i do this?

Comment: The type system is lost at compile time, so it won't be available at runtime https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469856/do-typescript-generics-use-type-erasure-to-implement-generics

Comment: I'm trying to get the type of a class which is calling the generic method.  `For Ex: getAll<SubscriberData>`  i want to get the type `SubscriberData` inside that method.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: To push some more parameters to the http call and alter http url by checking this condition based on a type.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can access the constructor reference of a class in a class decorator, a property in a property (or accessor) decorator, or a parameter in a parameter decorator (using [reflect-metadata](https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata)).

Unfortunately, generic type arguments are not available at runtime this way, they'll always yield the runtime equivalent of a simple `Object` type.

Instead, you can supply the constructor reference, which you can also use to infer the generic type (i.e. instead of specifying the generic type, you specify the corresponding constructor reference of that generic type):

```
export class BaseService {
    public getAll<T>(TCtor: new (...args: any[]) => T): Observable<T> {
        // get type of T
        const type = typeof(TCtor);

        // ...
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
new BaseService().getAll(DataClass); // instead of 'getAll<DataClass>()'
```

[Demo on playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20BaseService%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getAll%3CT%3E(TCtor%3A%20new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20T)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20get%20type%20of%20T%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20type%20%3D%20typeof(TCtor)%3B%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20TCtor()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20DataClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20dataObj%20%3D%20new%20BaseService().getAll(DataClass)%3B%0D%0AdataObj.id%3B%0D%0AdataObj.name%3B)

The type `new (...args: any[]) => T` simply says: a newable type (i.e. a class/constructor) that returns the generic `T` type (in other words, the corresponding class/constructor for the generic `T` instance type).

Comment: Notice that *'@angular/core'* exports `Type` that can be used instead of `new (...args: any[]) => T`, e.g. `public getAll<T>(ctor: Type<T>): Observable<T> {...`.